# Understanding notation for functions used in JavaScript documentation

Tags: javascript, syntax, callback

Whenever I see any syntax in JS, it is written in this format

```
response.writeHead(statusCode[, statusMessage][, headers])
or
window.setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);
```

Why everyone use that array kind of notation and why the comma is mostly place inside of the array ????
To denote a callback as well this syntax is used, can't understand why?

Comment: That's neither array nor JS syntax at all. That's _**optional parameters**_ notation.

Comment: That isn't JavaScript syntax, but its documentation.  That style isn't specific to JavaScript but has been used in other languages for the last 30 years at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see this in documentation:

```
response.writeHead(statusCode[, statusMessage][, headers])
```

...it means you can call that method in one of the following ways:

```
response.writeHead(statusCode)
response.writeHead(statusCode, statusMessage)
response.writeHead(statusCode, headers)
response.writeHead(statusCode, statusMessage, headers)
```

So the square brackets in the syntax notation denote that something is optional. This means also that the comma must appear like that.

#### Dangling Commas

Your second example is in fact a less accurate descriptor:

```
window.setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);
```

because when taken too literally, it would seem to allow this:

```
window.setTimeout(func, );
```

but that is invalid syntax, at least in JavaScript what this syntax descriptor seems to be about.

#### Allowed Number of Arguments

The above descriptor does not clearly indicate that you can call this method with only 2 or 3 arguments, like for example:

```
window.setTimeout(alert('hi'), 100);
```

But clearly, this is understood to be the case. Some would prefer to write such a descriptor as:

```
window.setTimeout(func[, delay[, param1[, param2[, ...]]]]);
```

No-one will make an issue of the first descriptor: it is clear what is intended. It is part of documentation, not a strict language. In fact, the many brackets do not really add to the readability of such a descriptor. It is a matter of where to draw the line between exactness and clarity.

#### Ellipsis

Note also that the dots mean many more parameters could follow. This ellipsis is not to be taken as a literal either. This is not to be confused with ellipses that are part of some language syntaxes (e.g. Javascript [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)). This shows again this documentation convention is not a very strict language.

#### Multiple Bracket Pairs

Back to the first example. Note that the described method has two pairs of brackets. This actually has a meaning, and expresses a possibility that is not visible in this alternative descriptor that only has one pair:

```
response.writeHead(statusCode[, statusMessage, headers])
```

The difference is that this alternative does *not* allow this call:

```
response.writeHead(statusCode, headers)
```

If one would want to pass *headers*, then they also have to provide *statusMessage*:

```
response.writeHead(statusCode, statusMessage, headers)
```

However, the original descriptor does allow this. This means the described method is quite smart, as it supports two different interpretations for calls that are made with 2 arguments:

```
response.writeHead(statusCode, statusMessage)
response.writeHead(statusCode, headers)
```

This is obviously because values that have the meaning of *statusMessage* are distinguishable from values that have the meaning of *header*. In this particular case, nodejs treats the second argument as a *header* when it is an object, and as a *statusMessage* when it is a primitive value (string).